# Subprocess can't run Bash command after reinstalling binary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running `ansible-playbook` via something like

```
subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', "ansible-playbook some_playbook.yml"])
```

After uninstalling & reinstalling `ansible-playbook` my project somehow can't execute it anymore claims **"bash: ansible-playbook: command not found"**.

Facts:

- running on Ubuntu 20.04
- `ansible-playbook` was installed via `pip3`

Tried the following:

- ensured that the command is available and runnable via terminal & `python3`
- deleted the `venv` folder and reinstalled everything (using PyCharm does it automatically)
- deleted Bash cache via `hash -r` & `hash -d ansible-playbook`
- rebooted
- installed `pyclean` and ran it
- deleted `.idea` folder (PyCharm)
- recloned the repository into different directory and set up everything again. Same problem.
- created a dummy test in the same project folder and found out that it runs fine:

  ```
  > cat test.py 

  import subprocess
  process = subprocess.run(['bash', '-c', "ansible-playbook some_playbook.yml"])
  ```

Everything worked fine before the reinstall. My program also runs various Bash commands before executing `ansible-playbook` and I swear on my left testicle that it's not my code. There must be some hidden mystery cache I'm missing.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Your PATH probably doesn't include the directory where that program is. (It might be in ~/.local/bin.) Instead of using bash -c, you should be using either shell=True anyway, or preferably shutil.which() to (try to) locate the program.

Comment: @AKX Correct. It was in `~/.local/bin` and after reinstalling it globally it's now in `/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook`. Thanks a lot. Also thanks for the tip with `shell=True`, but I didn't have a problem with `bash -c` before. There is no escaping to do and you can just pass your command as variable. But according to the [subprocess FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) this seems to be solid advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

If you've installed the package as a regular user with a recent pip, it will have installed the libraries and binaries into `~/.local/bin` which isn't on PATH by default. (Pip will warn you about that.)

Once the binary is on PATH, you can skip the extra shell process (which is unnecessary and may cause Weird Things in certain situations) and not be vulnerable to shell injection attacks with

```
import subprocess, shutil

subprocess.run([shutil.which("ansible-playbook"), "some_playbook.yml"])
```